# jquery facebox plugin problem

Tags: jquery

this [jquery code](http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/) enable you to show the box when click any specific text
now i want it appear in the page start not in click
i mean when the page open
it appear automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="popup">
    Hello World
</div>
```

And the script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    if (document.getElementById("popup") != null) 
    {
        $.facebox($('#popup').html());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using getElementById? You can do the same in jQuery by simply using if($("#popup").length) {} :)

Comment: Marko, jQuery is slow. If it's a fast universal function that I can easily write, like getElementById, I'd rather use that, than $("# stuff, which is harder to read, slower, harder to type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can 
like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){$.facebox($(your_selecor_here);});
```